# Can't create new record in database through form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

**Controller**:

```
class PaintingsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @painting = Painting.new(gallery_id: params[:painting])
    end

    def create
        @painting = Painting.new(params[:painting])
        if @painting.save
            flash[:notice] = "Painting successfully added to gallery"
            redirect_to @painting.gallery
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

**galleries#show:**

```
<h1><%= @gallery.name %></h1>

.
.
.

<%= link_to 'Add a painting', new_painting_path(:gallery_id => @gallery) %>
```

**Model**:

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gallery_id, :image, :name, :remote_image_url
  belongs_to :gallery
end
```

**Form in paintings#new view**:

```
<%= form_for @painting do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :gallery_id %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :remote_image_url %>
        <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

When I submit this form I get an error that says:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PaintingsController#create...NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass: INSERT INTO "paintings" ("created_at", "gallery_id", "image", "name", "remote_image_url", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

I've never seen an error like this before so really confused about it. I guess it can't save the record to the database. But why is it calling *name* as a method?

Is there a way to fix this? any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: I thought you didn't need that when using `form_for`? It's just sqlite3

Comment: I guess it require not sure.Have you tried from console?

Comment: Yeah from console I can save a record.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was my model it should read as follows:

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gallery_id, :image, :name, :remote_image_url
  belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Because I was using Carrierwave to upload.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'Add a painting', new_painting_path(:gallery_id => @gallery) %>
```

You need to change the new action.

```
def new
        @painting = Painting.new(gallery_id: params[:gallery_id])
end
```

Comment: Whooops, yeah I had the name mixed up there. That makes the *gallery_id* correct but I'm still getting an error. It says there's something wrong in line 8 of the controller. A no method error for the `if @painting.save` line.

Comment: It is due to you already have saved some painting which do not have gallery id, you can make it error free by <h1><%= @gallery.name unless @gallery.blank? %></h1>

Comment: there are no paintings in the database at all but I will try this now @Bachan Smruty. And the error is in the post near the bottom. NoMethodError.. Undefined method 'name'